# A set can be written as disjoint union of half open intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

The above algebra of sets is used to define a pre-measure. The pre-measure  was said to be well-defined and finitely additive from the simple fact:

Each element in $ A$ can be uniquely written as a disjoint union of maximal left-open/right-closed intervals in $\mathbb R$.

I am trying to prove the simple fact but I cant seem to be able to show it.

A possible method: for all $x$ in E which is an element of A I tried to consider the union of all left-open\right-closed intervals in E that contained $x$. However, I don't know how to show the the union is still a half-open interval.(This is similar to showing that every open set is a countable union of disjoint intervals.)

Any ideas or suggestions as to how to prove the simple fact?

Comment: For each $x in E$ just look at the union of all $I_j$'s such that $x \in I_j$.

Comment: Yes I tried that but how do I show that the union is still half open

Comment: Union of  a finite number of half open intervals with a common point is the half open interval whose left end point is the minimum of the left end pints of the intervals and whose right end point is the maximum of the right end pints of the intervals

Comment: But how do you know there are only a finite number of half open intervals? The could be infinite half open intervals that contain x right?

Comment: By the way what is your definition of "left-open/right-closed interval"? Is $(0,+\infty)$ considered a "left-open/right-closed interval"?

Comment: No they are of the form (a,b]

Comment: $(0,+\infty)\in\mathcal A$, right? How would you write $(0,+\infty)$ as a  disjoint union of maximal left-open/right-closed intervals? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: we are just looking at the bounded intervals since the unbounded intervals would have measure infinity